# SQL Select Group By Min() - but select other

Tags: sql, firebird, greatest-n-per-group, filemaker

I want to select the `ID` of the Table `Products` with the lowest `Price` Grouped By `Product`.

```
ID    Product    Price
1     123        10
2     123        11
3     234        20
4     234        21
```

Which by logic would look like this:

```
SELECT
  ID,
  Min(Price)
FROM
  Products
GROUP BY
  Product
```

But I don't want to select the Price itself, just the ID.

Resulting in

```
1
3
```

EDIT: The DBMSes used are Firebird and Filemaker

Comment: So you need 1 and 3  as answer

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: I need this for Firebird and Filemaker where having min() does not seam to work. I thought this is more generic so I do not have to mention the DBS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebird Query- Return first row each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37014009/firebird-query-return-first-row-each-group)

Comment: @MichaelMüller but now we do `insert into Products (ID, Product, Price) values (5, 123, 10)` - and what should your select return ? 1, 5 or both ?

Comment: Does FileMaker has triggers? I think you better make a separate table that would contain proper `ID` and/or `Price` for every `Product`, automatically updated by the RDBMS as you edit the `Products` table.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't specify your DBMS, so this is ANSI standard SQL:

```
select id
from (
  select id, 
         row_number() over (partition by product order by price) as rn
  from orders
) t
where rn = 1
order by id;
```

---

If your DBMS doesn't support window functions, you can do that with joining against a derived table:

```
select o.id
from orders o
  join ( 
    select product, 
           min(price) as min_price
    from orders
    group by product
  ) t on t.product = o.product and t.min_price = o.price;
```

Note that this will return a slightly different result then the first solution: if the minimum price for a product occurs more then once, all those IDs will be returned. The first solution will only return one of them. If you don't want that, you need to group again in the outer query:

```
select min(o.id)
from orders o
  join ( 
    select product, 
           min(price) as min_price
    from orders
    group by product
) t on t.product = o.product and t.min_price = o.price
group by o.product;
```

Comment: I am sorry, Its Firebird and Filemaker.

Comment: @MichaelMüller Firebird 3 supports this syntax.

Comment: Thanks! For Filemaker "Over" and "Partition" does not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  ID
FROM  Products as A
where price = ( select Min(Price)
                from Products as B
                where B.Product = A.Product )
GROUP BY id
```

This will show the `ID`, which in this case is `3`.

Comment: This will not give you correct result as you are calculating only minimum price for all product not for grouped product