# How to select the latest contract for a customer if there is more than one in a period

Tags: python, sql, select, firebird

I am writing a simple Python program to check for expired service contracts in a Firebird database and create a report based on that query which will be used to send automatic e-mails to the customers.

The function is looking for about to be expiring contracts between two dates: date_from = today + 5days and date_to = today + 10days.
My code looks like this:

```py
t = (date_from, date_to)  # Create  tuple with both dates

print()
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT C_CUST_BULSTAT, C_CUST_NAME, C_OBJ_PHONE,C_ECR_NUMB, C_FROMDATE, C_TODATE, C_NUMBER, C_TYPE FROM CONTRACTS "
            "WHERE (C_TYPE = 2) "
            "AND (C_TODATE BETWEEN ? AND ?);", t)  # Make query matching the tuple
```

The problem I found is that if the customer comes today 22.01 and signs a new contract from 30.01.2022 to 30.01.2023 the system will have 2 contracts - one expiring and one renewed. According to my code - they will be notified about contract expiry which is wrong.
So basically from in case of two contract records with two C_TODATE only the higher should be taken into account and checked against dates matching criteria.

So when doing the checks I should take the contract with latest C_TODATE from the list. How I can do that?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This looks like a SQL question in the Firebird dialect, rather than specifically a python/FDB programming question.  I think you are asking, "how can I select the expiring contracts of only the most recent contracts per customer?"  Can you please show us your CREATE TABLE definition _with only the relevant fields_, and then show sample rows (e.g., one customer with two contract records, and one or two customers with only one contract record)?

Comment: Also, what version of firebird?

Comment: please, enter the sample table and data at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0 so we all could try different queries and you would explain which of resulting outputs are right and wrong, and WHY you consider them right or wrong

Comment: Voting to close as [already answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37014009/firebird-query-return-first-row-each-group).  I think you have a "greatest _n_ per group" sql question, in this case, the "greatest (most recent) _1_ per customer."  Once you have that, you can check for C_TODATE values BETWEEN your expiry window.